# Quicksort to order array by business key?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I've an array of objects, the size of which I cannot predict. The contents of the array are model objects with properties of type nsstring and nsnumber.

I need to sort the array according to one of the properties, an nsnumber. How would you do it in objective-c/Cocoa? Implement quicksort or some other algorithm (which one)? Any libraries that handle that for you?

**Update**
While the response below is correct, it only works on 10.6 and I'm targeting 10.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = [results allValues];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                    initWithKey:@"ordinalPosition" 
                      ascending:YES] 
                    autorelease];

NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray 
                       sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` has [several](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12) sorting methods. Given your array, `arr`,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"numberProperty" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArr = [arr sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

will give you an array sorted (ascending) by @"numberProperty". Obviously, you'll have to substitute the name of the `NSNumber` property in your model objects for `@"numberProperty"`.

The sorting algorithm is not specified in `NSArray`'s sorting methods.

Comment: I would add that the built-in sorts are almost always more efficient than anything you can implement by hand. You shouldn't even think of writing a custom sort before you have ironclad evidence that the built-in sorts are to slow.

Comment: +1: Sorting and Filtering NSArray objects: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/sortingFilteringArrays.html

Comment: Only available in 10.6, I'm developing for 10.5 at a minimum. Sorry for not mentioning on my post.

Comment: What? None of the methods mentioned requires 10.6. Sorting has been a part of Foundation for years and years now.

Comment: Perhaps you refer to the convenience factory method for NSSorDescriptor, whihc arrived in 10.6? Just replace it with the equivalent alloc/initWithKey:ascending:/autorelease.

Answer (score -2):

Use `qsort()` from stdlib.h.

Comment: If the questioner is using an `NSArray`, the stdlib's `qsort()` won't help very much.